# how can I get a list of all of the permissions a user has?

Tags: 8, users

if I have the current user object, how can i get a list of all of the permissions he has in drupal 8 custom module ?  I dont want to check for one particular permission which would be $current_user->hasPermission("permission_name").

I want to get the entire list of his permissions.

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Can you try the following snippet:

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$user_roles = $user->getRoles();
$roles_permissions = user_role_permissions($user_roles);
```

This will give you permissions grouped by roles.
But most likely you want them in one array.

Therefore you can use this

```
$final_array = array();
foreach ($roles_permissions as $role_key => $permissions) {
  foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    $final_array[] = $permission;
  }
}
```

In case you want to load different user than the currently logged-in user, you can use

```
$some_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(123);
```

Where 123 stands for the user id.
For more information:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8.2.x

Best regards,

Oleg

Comment: This will get the current logged in user, not any user. But, in theory the script/snippet could be modified to load a specific user by their id and then view the role permissions they have.

Comment: Yes @tenken, you are correct. I saw in the question $current_user, so I assumed we are talking about the currently logged in user.
#TODO, add a script for loading different user.